# Why is SystemJS unable to find modules and typings?

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, bundling-and-minification, systemjs

I'm trying to bundle an `Angular 2` app with `SystemJS Builder 0.15.31`. I cannot understand why SystemJS can't find the Angular modules or the typings.

**systemjs.config.js**

```
System.config({
    transpiler: "ts", // this is plugin-typescript 5.2.6
    typescriptOptions: { typeCheck: true, tsconfig: true },
    map: { app:'dev', '@angular':'node_modules/@angular' },
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.ts',
            defaultExtension: 'ts' ,
            meta: { '*.ts': {'loader':'ts'} }
        },
        '@angular/core':  {main: './bundles/core.umd.js', defaultExtension:'js'},
        ...
        "ts":             { main: "./lib/plugin.js"},
        "typescript": { // this is typescript 2.0.3
            main: "./lib/typescript.js",
            meta: {"./lib/typescript.js": {"exports": "ts"} }
        }
    }
});
```

**tsonfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "."
},
```

**systemjs-builder gulp task**

```
gulp.task('bundle', function() {
    var builder = new SystemBuilder();
    builder.loadConfig('./systemjs.config.js').then(function(){
            return builder.buildStatic('app', 'dist/bundle.js');
        });
});
```

When I execute the gulp task, this error is thrown:

> Cannot find module '@angular/core'

The path `node_modules/@angular/bundles/core.umd.js` is resolved correctly (If I change the file name, a `file not found` error ensues).

`SystemJS 0.19.39` and `plugin-typescript 5.2.6`

Comment: You tried adding `'@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',` to your `map:` ?

Comment: cont....where @npm is defined in `paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    }`

Comment: @bhantol If I move `@angular/core` from `packages` to `map`, I get the same exact errors. Neither the typings, nor the module can be found. If I set `@angular/core` in both `packages` and `map`, I see this error: `could not find 'root\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js\bundles\core.umd.js'`

Comment: I am able to do what you did in the gulp task with all the `@angular/core` etc. mappings in the `map:` - fyi I tried this in the angular quickstart. Creates the dist folder with no issues.

Comment: @bhantol the Quickstart doesn't use `plugin-typescript` or `systemjs-builder`

Comment: Learning this myself but try removing `"types": ["hammerjs","core-js"],` I am thinking because I came across `This tsconfig.json file will only include ./node_modules/@types/node, ./node_modules/@types/lodash and ./node_modules/@types/express. Other packages under node_modules/@types/* will not be included.`

Comment: @bhantol Getting rid of `types` gets rid of the first error only.

Comment: Actually, the path was resolved successfully (updated the OP). The module is just not found within the files